# oracle 11g installation issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle 11G enterprise edition. While installing I am able to do

1. Open installation wizard.
2. Hit next and goto installation option
3. I selected "create and configure a database" then hit next
4. when select "desktop" and hit next installation wizard is closing by itself.

I even tried starting the setup wizard as administrator but it didn't work. Thank you!

Last few lines in log.
SEVERE: You have not provided an email address.

Do you wish to remain uninformed of critical security issues in your configuration?
INFO: Completed validating state

INFO: Verifying route success

INFO: Get view named [InstallOptionsUI]

INFO: InstallOptionsUI Entering Constructor

INFO: InstallOptionsUI Exiting Constructor

INFO: View for [InstallOptionsUI] is oracle.install.ivw.db.view.InstallOptionsUI@5c17d6c1

INFO: Initializing view  at state

INFO: Completed initializing view  at state

INFO: Displaying view  at state

INFO: Completed displaying view  at state

INFO: Loading view  at state

INFO: Completed loading view  at state

INFO: Localizing view  at state

INFO: Completed localizing view  at state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: Executing action at state installOptions

INFO: Completed executing action at state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: Moved to state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: InstallOptions UI Entering & Exiting processInput

INFO: Validating view at state

INFO: Completed validating view at state

INFO: Validating state

INFO: Completed validating state

INFO: InstallOptionsAction Actions.transition called

INFO: selectedInstallOption is :INSTALL_DB_AND_CONFIG

INFO: inventory location isC:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory

INFO: Is CRS Installed false

INFO: launchNETCA = true

INFO: Verifying route system_class

INFO: Get view named [SystemClassUI]

INFO: SystemClassUI Entering Constructor

INFO: SystemClassUI Exiting Constructor

INFO: View for [SystemClassUI] is oracle.install.ivw.db.view.SystemClassUI@26a150e

INFO: Initializing view  at state

INFO: inventory location isC:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory

INFO: Is CRS Installed false

INFO: Completed initializing view  at state

INFO: Displaying view  at state

INFO: Completed displaying view  at state

INFO: Loading view  at state

INFO: Completed loading view  at state

INFO: Localizing view  at state

INFO: Completed localizing view  at state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: Executing action at state getSystemClass

INFO: Completed executing action at state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: Moved to state

INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations

INFO: Completed background operations

INFO: SystemClassUI Entering & Exiting processInput

INFO: Validating view at state

INFO: Completed validating view at state

INFO: Validating state

INFO: inventory location isC:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory

INFO: Is CRS Installed false

INFO: Completed validating state

INFO: selectedSystemClass is :DESKTOP_CLASS

INFO: Verifying route desktop_class_yes

INFO: Get view named [QuickInstallUI]

Comment: When the dbca is running it gives you a log output directory. Inside of that directory are 8 or 9 log files. Can you give us the last 50 or so lines of the last updated one?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this issue. I think there was some issue with user account settings. So, I created a new user and I tried to install. It worked.